# Terminal app that uses the entire terminal window

Tags: c#, terminal, console

I've seen terminal apps, such as vim, that when used fill the whole screen and then disappear entirely when they are quit, i.e. they do not simply print into the current terminal "space":

[image: Vim, when opened, takes up the whole terminal window, and when closed prints nothing else in the terminal.]

I was wondering how in C# I can accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program uses the *alternate screen* feature of the terminal (originally xterm, but others).

vim is using the terminal description, which includes escape sequences for starting and ending the use of cursor-addressing.  Mostly (for xterm and imitators) that switches to/from the alternate screen, saving/restoring the cursor position in the normal screen.  Not all terminal descriptions use the feature.

A history of the feature is given in the xterm FAQ [Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite).  Originally this was (in terminfo format)

```
smcup=\E7\E[?47h, rmcup=\E[2J\E[?47l\E8,
```

(where `\E` is the ASCII escape character `\033`), and the [modern version](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-xf86-v40) is

```
smcup=\E7\E[?1049h, rmcup=\E[?1049l
```

Referring to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx), this probably will work for **`\E7\E[?47h`**:

```
System.Console.Write("\u001b7\u001b[?47h")
```

The **`\E`** becomes **`\u001b`**.  Similarly, for **`\E[2J\E[?47l\E8`**, you could write

```
System.Console.Write("\u001b[2J\u001b[?47l\u001b8")
```

Further reading:

- [How to Not Overwrite Previous Terminal Contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628932/how-to-not-overwrite-previous-terminal-contents/31630250#31630250)
- [How curses preserves screen contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188508/how-curses-preserves-screen-contents/39190527#39190527)
- [Temporarily clear the terminal in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33205630/temporarily-clear-the-terminal-in-linux/33211753#33211753)

Comment: And how can I use the alternate screen in C#?

Comment: What is the escape sequence? You do not  mention it.

Comment: I see you've edited your answer to include what the escape sequences are, but how do I actually use C# to "print" them to the console?

Comment: I get "error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence '\E'" when i try `System.Console.Write("\E7\E[?47h")`

Comment: try `System.Console.Write("\0337\033[?47h")`

Comment: That literally prints "33733[?47h"

Comment: What about rmcup? I tried looking through your link ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx)) but couldn't find any references.

Comment: Why aren't you using what you called "the modern" version?

Comment: because you asked about the older one where you commented about "error CS1009:"